# php require and white space

Tags: php, whitespace, require

I was wondering if there was a way to slightly modify the require or include functionality so that it removes line breaks and white space. So it minifies all the html / js inside the documents that im trying to grab.

I tried this:

```
trim(require('my document.php'));
```

didn't work though, is there a correct way to do this?

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: what kind of break and spaces? Could you kindly give detailed information?

Comment: Removed my answer, I thought you wanted to remove whitespace from the source-NAME. My bad :). Anyway: removing all breaks and whitespace is not smart, for it will change `<a href` into `<ahref`, which is obviously wrong. Same goes for .js. I think the only answer is: don't try to do this on the fly. It will cost you more (minify your code can be expensive) than it will help you. Just do it in advance

Comment: Minifying HTML/JS isn't as simple as just removing all whitespace. You'll want to use a minifier library.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make much sense to just remove all whitespace. If the server is configured correctly to use compression when it serves the files, whitespace makes very little difference.

Comment: The reason i want to do this is to improve the speed of page loads. I just figure that if i am going to use includes, why not optimise while i do it.

Comment: I see what you mean about white space and causing issues like <ahref, so i guess that's out. And what i'm hearing from you guys is that line breaks and white space don't make much difference with load speed. A minify library looks interesting though. IF you guys think minifying on the spot is a bad idea, i believe you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like

```
ob_start();
require('my document.php');
echo minify(ob_get_flush());
```

Which will get all the output generated by my document.php and minify it, you have to find a minifying library to do it though.

Comment: this is kind of what im after

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write or use a parser of some sort to do the job properly. If you can use a rough and ready solution then str_replace will take an array and replace with a single character

e.g. str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", "etc"), " ", $mystring);

But that seems like a lot of processing for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Someone downvoted this without offering an alternative solution. I don't get this site. Is it full of w@nkers or something?

Comment: I don't mind finding out I'm wrong. I'm here to learn, but what's the point of this kind of behaviour?

Comment: this is what i thought i could do, as if a require would behave like a variable, but it doesn't work like that :P

Comment: No. It isn't a variable. You could try file_get_contents() if that is what you want. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: file_get_contents - interesting i might look into that

Answer (score 0):

this question makes no sense.

1. Removing whitespaces makes no sense itself. If it's such a big concern, you can set up your server to send compressed contents, it will reduce bandwith.
2. Yet why to clean whitespace in the included files output only? Why not to do it for the whole site output at once?

Comment: Every big does it, Look at google.com source. It's perfectly fine to remove all new line, carriage return tab char and double space because they are useless

Comment: ... good question - i think you are right, why not just do the whole page at once

Answer (score 0):

**What you're describing is potentially fragile** and vastly inferior to simply [enabling compression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression).

It would be helpful if you update your question to say why you would want to do this.

However, you can do it like this:

```
 ob_start();
 require('file');
 echo = preg_replace(array("@[\r\n\t]+@", '@>\s+<@', '@\s+@', '@\s?{\s?@', '@\s?}\s?@'), array('', '><', ' ', '{', '}'), ob_get_clean());
```

Even so you'll likely find you manage to remove whitespace that you need - especially if you are running it on javascript and miss a semicolon.

Comment: okay cool, so it sounds like im going about this all wrong - thanks for your advice